# API to expand call handling? SIP support

Tags: sip, voip, firefox-os

I'm having a hard time finding the API level of Firefox OS where I might hook
up SIP handling (and, post call setup, 711 or what-have-you media streams).
Is there an open API at this level yet?

Answer (score 1):

There is no SIP handling API currently in Firefox OS, but we are working on WebRTC.  I am not sure that would meet your needs though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sipML5 brings you further.
http://sipml5.org/